# __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info and __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info errors with STM32F4, C And C++ combined

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, embedded, stm32

I'm working on an embedded project in which I use *nucleo STM32F446RE Board*. I'm using CubeMX and before I generate the code, I select the Makefile option in the toolchain/IDE box. I'm writing the code in vs code. As part of advancing in the project, as soon as I'm done with the embedded part, I'm starting to work with ROS.

The first thing I need to perform is rosserial for STM32 and it requires to work with a C++ code. When I work with the ROS code I'm getting these errors: `undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'` and `undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'`.

After running some tests and searching online I understand that the problem is with the virtual methods. I wanted to examine the problem by creating a mini project that could explain the issue. In the attached code I added you can see 2 classes: Base class and Derived class, as well as a define in the code named: *VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON* that's meant to separate 2 modes.

I'm using virtual method when the *VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON* is defined and not using it when the *VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON* is commented. When I don't use the virtual method, the code runs perfectly but when I do use it, I'm getting the same errors as before.

I've read that some people think that the problem is with a reading of a specific compiler if it's gcc or g++ and that there are some flags that can fix it, but I didn't really understand how to do it. Also it's worth mentioning that I had changed the end of the main file in order to be able to run it with **C++** to main.cpp. I can't work with a different workspace or toolchain, I have to work with vs code and Makefile. Would really appreciate it if anyone knows the issue and can help me solve it in vs code. Thank you so much. The codes I added are main.cpp and the example classes I used to examined the problem.

*Edited: Included complete build-log and compiler/linker command invocations and
my Makefile.

`myClasses.h`

```
#include "main.h"
#define VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON // As I said, when I comment this line the code works fine

#ifdef VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON 
class Base {
   public:

    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void LED_ON() {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,LD2_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(300);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:

    Derived() {} 
    ~Derived() {} 
    void LED_ON() {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,LD2_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(30);
    }
};
#else
class Base {
   public:
    void LED_ON() {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,LD2_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(500);
    }
};
#endif
```

`main.cpp`

```
some code...

int main(void)
{
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  ...
  ...
  ...
  //some inits.....

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  #ifdef VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON
  Derived derived1;
  Base* base1 = &derived1;
  #else
  Base base1;
  #endif
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    #ifdef VIRTUAL_METHOD_ON
    base1->LED_ON();
    #else
    base1.LED_ON();
    #endif

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
   
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
some code...
```

`build-log and compiler/linker command invocations`

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\LedOnVirtualFunc> make -f STM32Make.make clean
rd /s /q build
PS C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\LedOnVirtualFunc> make -f STM32Make.make
mkdir build
arm-none-eabi-g++ -c  -feliminate-unused-debug-types -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/main.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/main.lst Src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal.o   
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c 
-o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.lst Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.lst Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c -o build/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/stm32f4xx_it.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/stm32f4xx_it.lst Src/stm32f4xx_it.c -o build/stm32f4xx_it.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/system_stm32f4xx.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/system_stm32f4xx.lst Src/system_stm32f4xx.c -o build/system_stm32f4xx.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -x assembler-with-cpp -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IInc -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/startup_stm32f446xx.d" startup_stm32f446xx.s -o build/startup_stm32f446xx.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/main.o build/stm32f4xx_hal.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o build/stm32f4xx_it.o build/system_stm32f4xx.o build/startup_stm32f446xx.o -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -specs=nosys.specs -TSTM32F446RETx_FLASH.ld  -lc -lm -lnosys  -Wl,-Map=build/LedOnVirtualFunc.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -o build/LedOnVirtualFunc.elf
c:/vsarm/armcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/main.o: in function `Derived::~Derived()':
C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\LedOnVirtualFunc/Inc/cppCheck.hpp:20: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
c:/vsarm/armcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/main.o:(.rodata._ZTI4Base[_ZTI4Base]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
c:/vsarm/armcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/main.o:(.rodata._ZTI7Derived[_ZTI7Derived]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/LedOnVirtualFunc.elf] Error 1
```

`Makefile`

```
##########################################################################################################################
# File automatically-generated by tool: [projectgenerator] version: [3.7.1] date: [Sun Dec 06 16:10:25 IST 2020]
##########################################################################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = LedOnVirtualFunc


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Src/main.c \
Src/stm32f4xx_it.c \
Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.c \
Src/system_stm32f4xx.c  

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32f446xx.s


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32F446xx


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-IInc \
-IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include





# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif





# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32F446RETx_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
  
#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

Comment: Include the complete build-log including the compiler/linker command invocations.  That is where the issue lies, not in the code.

Comment: I edited my question and added the compiler/linker command invocations.

Comment: You may now need to add your makefile content unless you can figure out whet you need to do from my answer.  You have a couple of other undefined references in the log not mentioned in your original question.  The same solution applies however for at least one of them I think.  If the missing `~Derived` persists you should post a separate question as it would then be a different issue than your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The link step is performed via the gcc driver here:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/main.o build/stm32f4xx_hal.o [...]
```

But the `gcc` default link invocation does not support C++, so will not implicitly link the C++ support and standard library.  For that you need to either add options to support C++ explicitly or more simply use `g++`.

Your "generic" makefile is clearly designed for C code projects only.  The quick-and dirty solution perhaps is to add:

```
LD = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)g++
```

Then change the link rule from:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@
```

to:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(LD) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@
```

However there is no explicit rule for C++ compilation, so it is I guess using an implicit rule.  You should therefore also define:

```
    CXX = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)g++
```

and

```
   CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
```

then add:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.cpp=.lst)) $< -o $@
```

You may want to add C++ specific options such as `-no-rtti` to `CXXFLAGS`

Note that all these rules are defined to trigger if a file called `Makefile` changes, but your makefile is called `STM32Make.make`, so the rules will not force a build if the makefile itself changes - be aware of that.  It is an odd means of doing that in any case, it would have been sufficient to make `Makefile` a dependency of the `clean` target.  Such are the issues in using "found code".

There is in fact no need to use a mix of `gcc` and `g++` in your build, it is simpler to use `g++` exclusively for mixed C / C++ projects.  Using `g++` to compile C code does not mean it will compiled as C++; GCC selects C or C++ compilation based on the filename extension regardless of whether you use `gcc` or `g++`, the difference between the two is apparent only at the link step.

You can also call `ld` directly to link, but you then have to explicitly link the libraries for both C and C++.

Comment: I see, do you think I can send you my Makefile so you could pinpoint where to adjust it? I tried to manage that file a few times but I guess I didn't do it right. I'd appreciate your help here as well and thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @Asi SO does not have direct messaging, questions are for the community to address.  Just update your question with the makefile as you did the build log.  How did you create the makefile or acquire it if you don't  know how it works?  Maybe if it is from some online project you can just link to it?

Comment: Makefile added to the Answer. The Makefile was created during the creation of the code, It was generated with CubeMX so I did not have to make any changes, I'm assuming that the default work in STM32 is C language so when we're combining C++ we get some errors, like the one I had.

Comment: @Asi If you read my previous comment (deleted), ignore it, it seems CubeMX is indeed blissfully unaware of C++.  You might consider using [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) it is C++ aware and incorporates CubeMX in any case save you messing around with dodgy makefiles you do not understand and cannot maintain.